# Changing Bookmark font size

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome v. 117.0.5938.132 and Windows 11.
Is there a way to reduce the font and icon size on Google Chrome BOOKMARK BAR ONLY? Just so i can show more bookmarks witout changing anythng else in Chrome nor Windows 11?